# Write css over text in ireports 1.3.0

Tags: html, jasper-reports

im using ireport 1.3.0 because my framework need it, but my question is, when i write text from some field in a textfield in a jasperreport, can i translate this text(html) to normal text but with same effects, for example:

```
INPUT:
asd <br> qwe

OUTPUT:
asd
qwe
```

I can translate it using a 'replace' by '\n' and its the same:

```
INPUT
asd \n qwe

OUTPUT:
asd
qwe
```

okay, so, there is another way to replace but for example the tag element ''?

```
INPUT :
qwe <b>asd</b>

OUTPUT:
qwe **asd**
```

Because i cant make it work, thanks you so much.

Comment: Does this version support markup?

Comment: what do u mean with markup? @AlexK

Comment: The last versions (3+ at least) support different markups. One of them is html. In this case you don't need replace some base tags to show simple html

Comment: [Markup Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/)

Comment: Oh yeah, i know, but i cant work with others versions, so thats why imm asking another way to do it, jasperreports 5.1 and uppers do it without problems @AlexK

Comment: You can write sriptlet on Java and use it. This code will be do the same - replace  tags and so on

Comment: can u make an example please? thanks